# In k3s, how can I promote a worker node to a master node?

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I currently have a Raspberry Pi-based Kubernetes cluster based on k3s which, while originally a single-master cluster, has now grown to the point at which it is practical to have multiple (odd-number) master nodes.

My question is - with regard to k3s specifically - is if there is a simple path to promote an existing worker node to a master node, other than removing it completely and reinstalling it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot "promote" worker node to master node. There is not switch you could flip and from now on worker would become a master.

Unless you are already using [external database](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/ha/#1-create-an-external-datastore), you cannot add more master nodes. If this is the case, you may need to reinstall the cluster.

Check [external database options](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/datastore/).

If you are already using external database, follow [k3s documentation on how to setup HA cluster](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/ha/#2-launch-server-nodes)

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. Having recently moved from Docker Swarm to k8s, I'm still working out all the differences. :)

Comment: Also notice that currently you also have the option for HA with embedded etc https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/ha-embedded/ where the only reuqirement is to have an odd number (like swarm as etcd uses raft as well)