# k3s without HA: how to switch master node?

Tags: kubernetes, etcd, k3s, rancher

Rancher documentation on k3s is quite nice and its HA support (both with external DB or embedded etcd) look nice, but I don't want/need an HA setup.

In case my master node fails, I don't mind having downtime while I re-create it or make a master out of another one, but I cannot find documentation how to *switch* master node.

Which files should I backup regularly (or host in NFS mount which is what I want to do) so I can easily re-setup the cluster with another server node but with the exact same state?

For the initial setup, we do:

- master: `curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh`
- worker: `curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | K3S_URL=\"https://${MASTER_IP}:6443\" K3S_TOKEN=\"${TOKEN}\" sh -s`

If I just re-run the scripts choosing another master, I'll have all the state lost. Is there a single directory I can copy/preserve (and an argument to pass to script to re-use it)?

Comment: I am also interested in knowing how to do this AFTER the master node has failed. However, according to this answer https://serverfault.com/a/1040944/301389 it's possible to add another master if you are using an external database.